# Crystal report sub report overlapping

Tags: crystal-reports, report, crystal-reports-8.5

I have developed crystal  report  with 4 sub reports. Data volume of the sub reports are depending on the demand of the report.
When I put in those sub reports inside detail block it overlapping each other depending on their data volume.
When I put them in it separate page headers by adding more Sections it duplicate in each pages since report has more than one pages.
How to overcome this issue ?
Version Crystal Report 8.5

Comment: I know that in more recent versions, you can make multiple Detail sections. Then you can put 1 sub-report into each Detail section.  Can you do that in 8.5?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I was splitting sections in version 8.0.

Comment: Yaa .I got it . Yes it can be split and  Right mouse button on details section ->Format Section ->Detail block -> Insert section .Now it is working fine .Thanks every one

Answer (score 6):

Yaa .Thanks Poweruser and  EvilBob22 
I got the answer.It can be split  by clicking Right mouse button on details section ->Format Section ->Detail block -> Insert section.Than drag the sub reports in to each sections.
For more info 
http://flylib.com/books/en/4.229.1.66/1/

Answer (score 2):

It can be split by clicking Right mouse button on Section Expert -> Deatils-> 
In the Deatils add the New Section...So there are two parts i.e. Datil a and Detail b. In the Detail a put your main Report and in the Detail b Put ur sub Report.......

May I hope This Solution is Helpful for u.......